# How to remove/add buttons in TouchKeyboard?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to develop a project using touchscreen in Delphi XE. However it looks like for `TouchKeyboard` component I can't modify or remove button in `TouchKeyboard` properties.

How to remove button in Delphi XE or add new button using `TouchKeyboard`?

Answer (score 1):

Chris Bensen did a [series of articles](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.de/2009/12/hacking-ttouchkeyboard-part-i.html) about TTouchKeyboard. There he shows how to export a shipped layout into xml, manipulate it and convert it back to a resource. Perhaps this can give you some hints.

In case the link to his blog doesn't work in the future, here are the CodeCentral items for the sources he mentions: 27543, 27571